# configuration.rb:14:in `instance_eval': (eval):16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting

Tags: mysql, ruby, mongodb, mongify

mongify database configuration on centOS.

While running the command in terminal `mongify check database.config`, I'm getting following error.

```
/home/hcdc/.gem/ruby/gems/mongify-1.3.1/lib/mongify/configuration.rb:14:in `instance_eval': (eval):16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from /home/hcdc/.gem/ruby/gems/mongify-1.3.1/lib/mongify/configuration.rb:14:in `parse'
from /home/hcdc/.gem/ruby/gems/mongify-1.3.1/lib/mongify/cli/options.rb:78:in `config_file'
from /home/hcdc/.gem/ruby/gems/mongify-1.3.1/lib/mongify/cli/options.rb:58:in `parse'
from /home/hcdc/.gem/ruby/gems/mongify-1.3.1/lib/mongify/cli/application.rb:27:in `execute!'
from /home/hcdc/.gem/ruby/gems/mongify-1.3.1/bin/mongify:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/mongify:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/mongify:23:in `<main>'
```

My database.config file

```
sql_connection do
  adapter     "mysql"
  host        "10.208.35.134"
  username    "root"
  password    "hcdc123"
  database    "test"
  batch_size  10000           
# This is defaulted to 10000 but in case you want to make that smaller (on lower RAM machines) end

mongodb_connection do
  host        "localhost"
  database    "test"
end
```

Comment: Please, improve your question. Give it a proper title. Write the first sentences in a clear and logical way, to be easier to quickly understand it.

Comment: End is missing in sql_connection Do block

Answer (score 3):

```
sql_connection do
  adapter     "mysql"
  host        "10.208.35.134"
  username    "root"
  password    "hcdc123"
  database    "test"
  batch_size  10000           
  # This is defaulted to 10000 but in case you want to make that smaller (on lower RAM machines)
end # <<< this must be in a new line

mongodb_connection do
  host        "localhost"
  database    "test"
end
```